# How to add intent on menu event

Tags: android

I want to call activity on menu event.I am new to android so i am trying to open new screen on delete option on menu, for this i write switch case but i didnt get how to call another activity in that please help me my code is

```
@Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
     {
         MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
         inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
         return true;
     }
     @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
     {
        switch(item.getItemId())
          {
            case R.id.delete:   Intent i= new Intent(this,deleteAct.class);
                                 startActivity(i);break;
            case R.id.edit://calling another  intent; break;
            case R.id.showall://calling another intent; break;
          }
       return true;
     }
```

please help me ..

Comment: What is the behavior you see ?

Comment: Note you can [format lines as code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) by indenting them four spaces. The "{}" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. Edit your question and try it out. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting.

Comment: what error did you noticed in the log file?

Comment: Can you elaborate the question more, as the code (delete case) looks quite ok to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neha... Did you declare the activity in the AndroidManifest.xml file as in:

```
<activity android:name= "deleteAct"
    android:label="@string/delete_act_title">
</activity>
```

Also, consider adding:

```
default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

JAL

Some code [here.](http://sites.google.com/site/jalcomputing/home/mac-osx-android-programming-tutorial/dialog-as-activity)